# Dual boot (Windows 8 + Linux Mint 17) UEFI system boot windows only

Tags: linux, windows-8, boot, linux-mint, grub2

I have been working on a dual boot system with windows 8 preinstalled and linux mint 17 for a month or so. After applying an update in linux grub loader does not appear and system only boots windows. I used boot-repair from a live cd... http://paste2.org/CFK6PCPs is where the boot info summary is posted... with no result. 
I manually reinstalled grub2 through terminal of a live cd ...although reinstallation and update is completed with no problems (except that I could not unmount in the end because it was in use) after the reboot still no grub2 loader shows up and the system immediately logs into Windows 8 ... any advice?

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem when I tried to dual boot Windows 8.1 and Fedora. After I booted into Windows, the Grub boot menu disappeared until I changed my BIOS settings, then it would work until I booted Windows again. These two links helped me solve the problem:

- http://www.zdnet.com/article/the-refind-boot-loader-for-uefi-systems-a-life-and-sanity-saver/
- http://www.rodsbooks.com/refind/installing.html#naming

Some PCs with UEFI firmware, especially HP ones, check every time they boot whether the default boot item is `/EFI/Microsoft/Boot/bootmgfw.efi` (the Windows bootloader), and if it is something different like GRUB, they reset it. The way to work around this is to replace `bootmgfw.efi` with `grubx64.efi`, which fools the PC into thinking that the Windows bootloader is the default.

To do this, you can move the original `bootmgfw.efi` file (the Windows bootloader) up one directory, then copy `grubx64.efi` to the folder where the Windows bootloader was and rename it. You'll also need to update the path to the original `bootmgfw.efi` in `/EFI/fedora/grub.cfg` so that GRUB can find Windows to boot it.

Comment: Oops, I didn't realize this question is a year and a half old until now.

Comment: Posting answers to old questions is very much okay, @tjohnson. We're not a forum just helping the one who asked a question, but we hope that all questions have value for future visitors too. So: thanks! :-)

Answer (score 0):

it's recommended to be aware of Dual Boot approaches and follow these threads generally:

- [Installing Ubuntu on a Pre-Installed Windows 8 (64-bit) System (UEFI Supported)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/221835/installing-ubuntu-on-a-pre-installed-windows-8-64-bit-system-uefi-supported)
- [How can I install Windows after I've installed Ubuntu?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/6317/how-can-i-install-windows-after-ive-installed-ubuntu)
- [Installing Ubuntu 13.10 alongside Windows 8.1](https://askubuntu.com/questions/399441/installing-ubuntu-13-10-alongside-windows-8-1)
- [How can I install Ubuntu without removing Windows?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1366/how-can-i-install-ubuntu-without-removing-windows)
- [Why don't I have the option ''Install Ubuntu alongside with them''](https://askubuntu.com/questions/69481/why-dont-i-have-the-option-install-ubuntu-alongside-with-them)
- [Ubuntu install and dual Boot with Windows 8 UEFI](https://askubuntu.com/questions/193103/ubuntu-install-and-dual-boot-with-windows-8-uefi)
- [Ubuntu 13.10 installer/live fails to boot from DVD/USB on UEFI](https://askubuntu.com/questions/385159/ubuntu-13-10-installer-live-fails-to-boot-from-dvd-usb-on-uefi)
- [Install Ubuntu next to Windows 8 (UEFI dual boot)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/236787/install-ubuntu-next-to-windows-8-uefi-dual-boot)
- [Windows 8 removes Grub as default boot manager](https://askubuntu.com/questions/235567/windows-8-removes-grub-as-default-boot-manager)
- [Windows 8 deletes GRUB when booting](https://askubuntu.com/questions/447201/windows-8-deletes-grub-when-booting)

Comment: @Ramhound Look attentivelyt - the bunch of links leads to SE resources only, so we don't mark as `duplicate` sometimes when lots of good answers exist here on SE. It is helpful to accumulate good answers at one place

Comment: I saw there were SE resources.  Doesn't meant you can't quote some of the material.  Questions have a habit of disappearing after years, seen it before, even questions I found extremely helpful are now gone.

Comment: @Ramhound well, okay, but either way I don't have a direct answer on how to do dual boot specifically with Mint 17 at the moment, so I would leave as it is for now. But thanks for your comment, it will be taken into account next time.